# Removing parentheses in partial derivative from diffcoeff package

Tags: math-operators, mathtools, diffcoeff

From a post and comment from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476164/partial-derivative-with-respect-to-three-variables)

Is there a way to remove the parenthesis in the denominator of the partial derivative?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools, diffcoeff}
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \[
    \abs*{\diffp[k_1,k_2,l]{u_0}
               {x_1, x_2, t}} \leq C
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `long-var-wrap=dv` inside the options of this package. Please, look at my example. It solves your problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{diffcoeff}
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
    \diffdef{p}
       {
    long-var-wrap=dv
        }
    \begin{document}
    
    \[
    \abs*{\diffp[k_1,k_2,l]{u_0}
               {x_1, x_2, t}} \leq C
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image: This is how it looks!]